# Evaluate the integral without substitution 2

Tags: calculus

So I am trying to solve this integral only by knowing the table of derivatives, can this be solved that way, can someone give me a hint ?
[image]

Comment: well the top of the fraction is a multiple of the derivative of the bottom so I guess that means you can kind of use the tables, but that's a substitution too!

Comment: got it friend, thanks @danimal

Answer (score 3):

Hint: it is
$$
\int  (\sin x -\cos x)^{-\frac{1}{5}}d(\sin x -\cos x) 
$$
and from the tables you know $\int u^adu$

Comment: '_evaluate the integral without substitution_ '

Answer (score 0):

By trigonometric transformations

$$\int\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\sqrt[5]{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt2\sin(x+\frac\pi4)}{\sqrt[5]{-\sqrt2\cos(x+\frac\pi4)}}dx.$$

Disregarding the phase shift and the constant factors, the expression is of the form $\sin(x)\cos^\alpha(x)$, which you might find in a table.